# resize the Hosting View through addSubview in Core-Plot in XCode 4

Tags: iphone, view, graph, resize, core-plot

I'm running into a wall trying to resize the Hosting View.  The problem is I either get a full-screen plot or a blank screen.  I'm hoping to get some leads to fix this problem:

I'm using Xcode 4 | IOS 4.3 | Recently downloaded core plot using hg:

I have two xib files (MainWindow & my ViewController)
My ViewController.xib file contains two objects: a View and Hosting View both at the same level:
+-View
+-Graph Hosting View

I get no erros in my code, but all I get a blank screen. I've searched for 3 days how to get around this problem, but haven't found something that works.

My xAppDelegate.h

```
 #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
  @class CorePlotTestViewController;
  @interface CorePlotTestAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {

  }

  @property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
  @property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet CorePlotTestViewController *viewController;
  @end
```

My ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
  #import "CorePlot-CocoaTouch.h"
  @interface CorePlotTestViewController : UIViewController <CPTPlotDataSource>
  {
    CPTXYGraph *graph;
    NSMutableArray *dataForPlot;
    CPTGraphHostingView *graphView;
  }
  @property(readwrite, retain, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *dataForPlot;
  @property(nonatomic, retain)IBOutlet CPTGraphHostingView* graphView;
```

My ViewController.m

```
 #import "CorePlotTestViewController.h"

  @interface CorePlotTestViewController(private)
  - (void) configureTableHeader;
  @end

  @implementation CorePlotTestViewController

  @synthesize dataForPlot;
  @synthesize graphView;

  -(void)dealloc 
  {
    [dataForPlot release];
    [super dealloc];
  }

  - (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self configureTableHeader];
  }
  - (void) configureTableHeader
  {
  // here I implement the contents of the Hosting View
  graph = [[CPTXYGraph alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectZero];
  CPTGraphHostingView *hostingView = [(CPTGraphHostingView *)[CPTGraphHostingView alloc]  
     initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
  [self.view addSubview:hostingView]; 
  ...
  // etc
  ...
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, you initialize the hosting view using a `CGRectZero` frame, which is basically a frame with an origin at (0,0) and both a width and a height of 0 px. It is the reason why you don't see the graph at all when you run your project.

If you gave a custom size and location to the hosting view in Interface Builder, it is overridden by this code.
By the way, I'm not sure why you want to add the hosting view to the controller's view in the code. You just need to layout both components using Interface Builder, giving the hosting view the size and the location you want it to have.

Last thing : why do you add a 'T' to Core-Plot class names ? `CPTPlotDataSource` should simply be `CPPlotDataSource`; `CPTXYGraph`: `CPXYGraph`; etc.

Comment: Thanks, that's right I was able to fix this as you suggest here.  I add the T, cause the latest version returns a bunch of errors with out the T, so I don't know if this was modified in the latest version of CP.  I was wondering whey all examples don't have the T.  Isn't it weird!?

Comment: Yeah it is weird. Are you sure you got a release version of Core-Plot, and not a debug version?